# Spring Batch Data Migration

Tags: mysql, migration, spring-batch

I am working on a project where the data from old database is to be migrated and/or merged with the new database after processing.  I have more than 500 tables in the old db.  The master data (Ids) in both the database are not matching with each other, so I decided to create mapping tables where old and new Ids will be kept, which will be used in later stage of migration.

So I decided to use Spring Batch for the same. However soon I realized that I cannot compare the data from old and new database, because the data can be read from single data source at a time. 
My questions is, is there any way to do this with spring batch? Is there any another better way to migrate the data.
My scenario is as follows.

### Old DB

```
Table Name – bank 
bankId  bankName
1           IDBI
2           HDFC
3           SBI
```

### New DB

```
Table Name – bank
bankId  bankName
1           SBI
2           Bank Of India
3           IDBI
4           HDFC
```

### Required Output

```
Table Name – migrate_bank
oldBankId   newBankId
1           3
2           4
3           1
```

Comment: i dont think you can use spring batch with this kind of requirement. i guess you will have to find a way to read from 2 different datasources in your program. May be read from 1st datasource keep all data in a cache and later read from the 2nd datasource and do you comaprison

Comment: If old-db is in 'read-only' mode and SB metadata tables are stored in new-db you can use SB without problem because transaction management is wrapper around new-db only